# LM386 doesn't work in Proteus

Tags: amplifier, simulation, proteus, lm386

I'm working on this project and I realized that the LM386 IC doesn't work in my Proteus application and the output is always zero.

I tried another symbol I downloaded from the Internet too but none of them are working. All other components are working correctly in my Proteus application.

Can anyone help me with what should I do to run this simulation correctly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have a working model of the LM386? also, what's the impedance of your speaker model? Also, your input signal, what's the amplitude range?

Comment: Symbol != simulation model. Downloading just symbol doesn't makes it magically simulated. And no, Proteus can't just simulate every part you want to. Only those it has simulation models for.

Comment: as you see in the picture that I uploaded some minutes ago, there is a schematic model for that too.

Comment: @hamedmohammadi schematic model aren't simulation model. These are different things. If something didn't came bundled with Proteus, in 99.99% of cases you won't find a Proteus simulation model for it on the Internet. Was it bundled with Proteus or you've downloaded this component somewhere?

Comment: @NStorm yes it was bundled with proteus

Comment: The simulation shows no audio input signal. Then of course the output level is also zero.